# LinkedIn Android SDK issue with access token : access token is not set. while authorization

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I wanted to share a post to LinkedIn using LinkedIn android SDK. Previously, It was working fine. but from past few days, suddenly I am getting the exception **"access token is not set"**.

The code I am using for login:

```
public void login(final OnAuthorization onAuthorization) {

    if (context instanceof Activity) {

        Scope scope = Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS, Scope.W_SHARE, Scope.RW_COMPANY_ADMIN);
        LISessionManager.getInstance(context).init((Activity) context, scope//pass the build scope here
                , new AuthListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthSuccess() {
                        onAuthorization.onAuthSuccess();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
                        // Handle authentication errors
                        onAuthorization.onAuthFailure(error);
                        Log.e("linkedin error ", "Auth Error :" + error.toString());

                    }
                }, true);//if TRUE then it will show dialog if
        // any device has no LinkedIn app installed to download app else won't show anything
    }
}
```

here `OnAuthorization` is an interface for notifying success and failure for LinkedIn.

```
public interface OnAuthorization {
    void onAuthSuccess();

    void onAuthFailure(LIAuthError liAuthError);
}
```

On successful LinkedIn authentication (login). sharing is done.

```
public void share(BlogInfo blogInfo, final OnSharingComplete onSharingComplete) {

    String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares";

    Visibility visibility = new Visibility(Visibility.CODE_ANYONE);
    Content content = new Content(blogInfo.getTitle(), blogInfo.getContent(), blogInfo.getBlogUrl(), blogInfo.getImageUrl());

    LinkedInShareRequestModel linkedInShareRequestModel = new LinkedInShareRequestModel(blogInfo.getDate(), visibility, content);

    Log.e("gson", new Gson().toJson(linkedInShareRequestModel));

    APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(context);

    apiHelper.postRequest(context, url, new Gson().toJson(linkedInShareRequestModel), new ApiListener() {
        @Override
        public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
            // Success!
            Log.d("", "Share response : " + apiResponse.toString());
            onSharingComplete.onComplete(true, null);
            logout();
        }

        @Override
        public void onApiError(LIApiError liApiError) {
            // Error making POST request!
            Log.e("", "Share error : " + liApiError.getLocalizedMessage());
            onSharingComplete.onComplete(false, liApiError);
        }
    });

}
```

here, `BlogInfo` is a model which is as following

```
public class BlogInfo implements Parcelable {

public static final Creator<BlogInfo> CREATOR = new Creator<BlogInfo>() {
    @Override
    public BlogInfo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new BlogInfo(in);
    }

    @Override
    public BlogInfo[] newArray(int size) {
        return new BlogInfo[size];
    }
};
private int id;
private String title;
private String subTitle;
private String content;
private String date;
private String imageUrl;
private String blogUrl;

public BlogInfo(int id, String title, String subTitle, String content, String date, String imageUrl, String blogUrl) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.subTitle = subTitle;
    this.content = content;
    this.date = date;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.blogUrl = blogUrl;
}

public BlogInfo(String title, String subTitle, String content, String date, String imageUrl, String blogUrl) {
    this.title = title;
    this.subTitle = subTitle;
    this.content = content;
    this.date = date;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.blogUrl = blogUrl;
}

private BlogInfo(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
    title = in.readString();
    subTitle = in.readString();
    content = in.readString();
    date = in.readString();
    imageUrl = in.readString();
    blogUrl = in.readString();
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getSubTitle() {
    return subTitle;
}

public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
    this.subTitle = subTitle;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getBlogUrl() {
    return blogUrl;
}

public void setBlogUrl(String blogUrl) {
    this.blogUrl = blogUrl;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {

    parcel.writeInt(id);
    parcel.writeString(title);
    parcel.writeString(subTitle);
    parcel.writeString(content);
    parcel.writeString(date);
    parcel.writeString(imageUrl);
    parcel.writeString(blogUrl);
}
}
```

and `OnSharingComplete` is again an interface for notifying whether sharing is successfully done or for failures.

```
public interface OnSharingComplete {
    void onComplete(boolean isSuccessful,Exception exception);
}
```

Can anybody help me with the error.??

Comment: Have you checked the Documentation Recently ? If not then do check it . Maybe they have made some changes .

Comment: @ADM yes, I've seen the new documentation. But, I don't know what to do in my case. I mean I am using Android linkedin SDK.

Comment: Hi, @Riddhi 
I am also facing the same issue. so please let me know whenever you got the solution.

Comment: @ChetanKumarPatel I still don't know the solution.

Comment: @Riddhi, Thanks for giving the answer. It's ok. :)

Comment: Hello @Riddhi, I found a solution for LinkedIn. Use OAuth 2 functionality of LinkedIn in place of Linkedin SDK. For more information, please follow this link. https://medium.com/@ellesmuse/how-to-get-a-linkedin-access-token-a53f9b62f0ce

Comment: @ChetanKumarPatel thanks for the link. I will surely try it.

Comment: @Riddhi did you find the solution?

Comment: @JaydipUmaretiya not yet. But you can try above link.  have not tried it yet.

Comment: @Riddhi It looks like confusing with the android code. :D

Comment: @ChetanKumarPatel I tried to follow the link you've mentioned but i am not getting idea on how to implement it in android.

Comment: @Riddhi, if you need any help regarding this issue then you can msg me on whatsapp if you don't mind and please tell me what's problem arries while you trying from that link

Comment: @Riddhi, you have to use webview in your activity and implementation like which is mentioned in that link